# How do you compare 2 dates in shell script (date is in git log format)

Tags: bash

I am logging the commits from Git, to a text file; I have multiple repository, so I put them all on a file, sequentially.

Now I would like to know which one is the latest commit, so I can put it in another report that I prepare at a certain interval.

Is there a quick way to compare these dates, without go for the route of extrapolate the string with the date and time, convert it in seconds and then compare the 2 numbers?

The output on my log file is the output of

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %an %ad" -1
```

which gives a line like this:

```
ar9dfv4 user Mon Jun 9 14:30:33 2014
```

Comment: Use the `%ai` format for dates and you can just sort them alphabetically (if all the work comes from the same timezone).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that option. Now that I have a date in that format thou; I don't understand how do you sort them alphabetically, if they are numbers.

Comment: doh! Indeed using sort is doing the sorting on its own, without any need to even tell which field is the date. Thanks a lot! Please add it as answer, so I can mark this as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `%ai` format for dates, you can use `sort` to sort the items asciibetically starting from the 3rd column.

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %an %ai" | sort -k3
```

I'm not sure what happens if different developers live in different time zones, though. You might need to convert the dates and times to a common zone, if git doesn't do it already.